# Yosemite Server: Spotlight from client

Tags: spotlight, server.app, search, client

I just bought a Mac mini to use as our office server (Yosemite).

How can I **search the shared folders with Spotlight from my client** iMac?

I tried to connect via SMB and AFP (Go > Connect to Server > afp://192.168.178.44). I tried to use Mavericks (my iMac) and my MacBook Air with 10.10 installed.

When I use Spotlight on the server itself, Spotlight will find my test file. The files I am searching for are on a new partition (/Volumes/HD2/dir/sharedfolder/).

I even have added Spotlight as user user and group to my shared folder (Icon with one person and two persons on it).

mdutil -s /Volumes/* (from a client terminal) says

```
/Volumes/team:
    Server search enabled.
```

Hope for some help :-) I bought an OSX server because just of Spotlight. Before we used a NAS and needed a better search.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a Mac running OS X Server in order to take advantage of Spotlight.  Personally, I have a Synology NAS with AFP, SMB and NFS shares that Spotlight has indexed.  (I do avoid SMB because it is much slower than AFP or NFS)

From the ***client*** (iMac or Macbook Air) mount the shared folder as you normally would

From terminal on the **client** run the command:

```
mdutil -i Volumes/<mount-point>
```

The "-i" tells mdutil to enable indexing.  The "-s" only prints the indexing status.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While this is true (afaik) that kind of index will be destroyed when you disconnect the shared volumen (right?)